# Amarok only shows 6 tracks even though there's way more than that

Tags: amarok

I'm using Amarok 2.5.0 on Kubuntu 12.04. Only 6 tracks show up in my local collection, but dynamic mode plays all the tracks in my collection as it should. How do I get all the tracks to show up in my local collection view?

Answer (score 3):

Answered by OP in comments:

> Unchecking my Music folder in the preferences and then checking it again fixed it.